# cannot write file after user is logon on windows

Tags: python, windows, file-io, startup

I have wrote a program to write some text to "log.txt" file when user is logged on (I added this program as a task to task scheduler with a trigger "At log on"). To check whether program will be started, I also add some code to let it show a window.

```
from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide.QtGui import *
import sys
import logging

# file writing test, failed
logging.basicConfig(filename='log.txt', level=logging.DEBUG)
logging.info('loaded logging module')

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
w = QWidget()
vbox = QVBoxLayout()
w.setLayout(vbox)

# file reading test
f = open('d:\write_file.py')
text = f.read()
f.close()

vbox.addWidget(QLabel(text))
w.show()

app.exec_()
```

Then after rebooting the system, I can see the window is displayed, but "log.txt" file is even not existed! Why is this happening?

PS. I have freeze the script to exe using PyInstaller, if it helps

Comment: does your reading test succeed? you could try omitting the "d:\", logging to the same folder as the program for testing purposes.

Comment: @benjamin Yes, the reading test succeed. Because I saw that the loaded text is displayed in the window. Thanks for the advice, I have edited it.

Answer (score 1):

The task scheduler runs as a specific system user, not as the user that just logged on. This means your code doesn't have the permission to change the user's files.

While you can specify the user which task scheduler should use, you can't say "current user".

You have two options:

1. Put the file into the Autostart folder where it will be executed by the login code as the user.
2. Change the permissions of the file that you intend to write and give the scheduler user write permission.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This program will be blocked by UAC on windows 7 if I added it to Autostart folder. And I found the creator of this task is "Administrator" and it will be ran as "Administrator".

Comment: @MarkMa: Did you try `RunAs` (http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/runas.mspx?mfr=true)

Comment: Unlike on Unix, the user "Administrator" on Window can't overwrite user files. To modify a file owned by another user, that user must give "Administrator" the permission "Modify" for this file. Alternatively, the Administrator can "take over" the file (effectively making it his file). In this case, you must give the original user permissions to access the file or they will be locked out.